# How can I prove the equality of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I prove the following for $a\ge 1$?
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{1}{(a+n)(a+n+1)} = \frac 1a
$$

Comment: What have you tried ?. Express the term as a difference of two terms and use the telescoping method....

Comment: Hint: partial fractions decomposition.

Comment: Any restrictions on $a$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $a>0$ and all non-negative integers $k$ we have
$$
\dfrac{1}{(a+k)(a+k+1)}=\dfrac{1}{a+k}-\dfrac{1}{a+k+1},
$$
therefore
$$
S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{1}{(a+k)(a+k+1)}=\sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{1}{a+k}-\sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{1}{a+k+1}=\dfrac{1}{a}-\dfrac{1}{a+n+1}.
$$
It follows that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{1}{(a+n)(a+n+1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{a}-\dfrac{1}{a+n+1}\right)=\dfrac{1}{a}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Partial Fraction Decomposition!

$\frac {1}{(a+n)(a+n+1)} = \frac{1}{a+n} + \frac{-1}{a+n+1}$

Now, our sum becomes:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{a+n}) -  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{a+n+1}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{a+n}) -  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{a+n}) = \sum_{n=0}^{0}(\frac{1}{a+n}) = \frac 1a$